# How do you setup a domain on a node.js server?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, vagrant, puppet

I'm learning node.js, have been setting up a vagrant/puppet development server using Ubuntu 14. How do you config a domain that would be used by the server -- does that depend on apache/nginx to setup a virtual host?

Comment: An HTTP server like Node.js will serve all requests that arrive at it, regardless of what domain they're sent to.

Comment: So if a domain is pointing at the IP of the server, the server will receive the packets? (Depending on listen port, I'm guessing)

Comment: Assuming there's nothing in the way (i.e. firewalls), yes.